# ASP.NET Gridview - How do I make all rows but the header row have a hover effect?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I'm trying to make all rows have a hover background except the header row.

Any tips?

I've got BoundFields, a TemplateField, and a CommandField.

Comment: How are you implementing hover effect?

Comment: Well, I'm not really implementing it at the moment.

As a temporary solution, I've got the following on my gridview's css-style: 

.MyClass tr:hover{
  background-color: #BBBBBB
}

Comment: then it is really simple, just use different class for the header!
 <HeaderStyle CssClass="..." />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [solution with example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MouseHoverUsingCSS.aspx).

Link Txt: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MouseHoverUsingCSS.aspx

Check out the screenshot as well.

[image]

Comment: I think this was the most elegant solution, so I accepted it as the solution. The others were great too so I upvoted them.

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented on client side using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#<%= grid.ClientID%> tr").not("tr:first-child").hover(
             function(){$(this).addClass("OnMouseOverClass");},//mouse-over
             function(){$(this).removeClass("OnMouseOutClass");});//mouse-out
      });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done

```
<asp:GridView... OnRowCreated="GvListingReport_RowCreated" />
```

And in the code

```
        public void GvListingReport_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD';this.style.cursor='hand'");

            ListingRecord record = e.Row.DataItem as ListingRecord;
            if (record != null)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:MM_openBrWindow('" + url + "','dec','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')");
            }

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';");
        }
    }
```

You can also make the hover effect maintain the colour for alternating rows.